# Query to compare values from last week to values generated today

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

I want to compare the total `TriggersStarted` (from `MetricName` column) from last week to `TriggersStarted` (from `MetricName` column) today

[image]

For that I am using the following query

```
AzureMetrics  | where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)  
              | where MetricName == "TriggersStarted"  
              | summarize count()
```

With this query, I got total count `TriggersStarted` from last 7 days but I got stuck at assigning that value to variable using `let`. And can I assign the result (from query) to a custom column using extend operator? And to compare to present day `TriggersStarted`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [toscalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction)()

```
let TriggersStarted_count = toscalar(
AzureMetrics 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d) 
| where MetricName =="TriggersStarted" 
| summarize count()
);
AzureMetrics
| count 
| extend TriggersStarted_count
```

| Count | TriggersStarted_count |
| --- | --- |
| 186235196 | 971 |

Comment: Thanks David i will explore toscalar function.Sorry about the question. i am looking to compare present day triggers  startedto sum of triggers started that were generated from last 7days. If last 7days trigger started is less than todays triggers started i will generate a alert based on the query